White House tour as an Indian tourist ? (Indian Embassy does not help)
Is there any way to get a tour of the White House (other than the POTUS inviting you), if your embassy does not organize any tours into the White House?
Indian Embassy does not organize White House tours.
I have heard you can accompany a US citizen if they are going, is that true ?

No foreign embassy can organize a tour of the White House. The White House staff organizes tours. But applications have to made either via a member of the Congress (in case of US citizens) or via a respective embassy in the Washington D.C. (in case of foreign nationals).
UPDATE: I've found several sources mentioning that embassies in DC (not just the Indian one) are indeed unwilling to apply for White House tours on behalf of their citizens. The only remaining option is to contact a member of the Congress. Foreigners of course have no MoC representing them, but there are reportedly some that accept requests from foreigners as well. One of them should be Eleanor Norton.
In any case, your odds are very low, since the demand far exceeds available slots. Even US citizens have it very hard to get a WH tour ticket.

Source
Source


Yes, clearly OP has read that page, because they've looked into that option and the Indian embassy does not facilitate tours. I fail to see how this is a useful answer.

Facilitating / organizing a tour is not the same as submitting an application for a tour (organized by someone else) on behalf of a citizen. That's what my answer is about.

The Indian embassy has made clear that they will not do this. So your answer does not help, nor answer the question (which is, can an Indian citizen join a tour which a US citizen requests from their congressperson)

@MJeffryes I've updated my answer to address that.

I still feel it doesn't quite address the actual question OP asked 'I have heard you can accompany a US citizen if they are going, is that true ?'

I don't think this answer is correct. The White House itself says "If you are a citizen of a foreign country, please contact your embassy in Washington, D.C." and gives ID requirements. So "No foreign embassy can organize a tour of the White House" is a sweeping statement that is unverified (except a post on Trip Advisor). But, I think that an applicant can book several people in the same group, so perhaps the OP's host can organise it, through their Member of Congress. There would seem to be no reason why the OP can't be booked in with a group.

Foreign embassies can't organize anything. They can submit an application on one's behalf. That's what I meant.

@Johnnyjanko I have already looked at the TripAdvisor pages. Also there is no way to contact Eleanor Norton without a US postal code. The main reason for asking this question was if there was a way for an American citizen to accompany to the White House.

@ng.newbie I couldn't find anything about that, but you can always ask a US friend of yours to submit an application (to a member of the Congress) in which they will mention you as another applicant. If someone else posts a better answer, I'll delete this one.
